# RuntimeException on SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm following this example.. https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager/src
  I tried implementing `setOnClickListener` for `Button` in `OnCreate`method and its getting force close.

Note: Without implementing `Button` its working fine..

code:

```
public class ABSTabsViewPagerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

Button b;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1"),
            FragmentOne.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2"),
            FragmentTwo.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 3"),
            FragmentThree.class, null);

}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your `setContentView(mViewPager)` have only viewpager. so there is no button in the present layout. you can't get button like this  `b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);`

set the full layout which has button also in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that the `Button`, that you're trying to reference by calling `findViewById()`, is not inside the root layout, because the root `View` is a `ViewPager`. You should create a layout where both the `ViewPager` and the `Button` are present. Hope this helps.